# Scala, sql interpolation for tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, tuples, scalikejdbc

I have a query that looks something like that in normal sql

```
Select * from persons 
where (persons.first_name, persons.last_name) 
in (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
```

I am trying to execute this from within scala

```
val names = List(("James", "hasi"), ("Michael", "Myers))
sql""" Select * from ${table}     where (first_name, last_name) IN ${names}""".stripMargin.map(...)
```

However it is failing since scalikejdbc doesn't know how to interpolate a tuple.

```
"PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance scala.Tuple2"
```

Any idea how to achieve that? I guess I can always transform the list of tuple into a string but the problem would be that scala will wrap it with single quotations, dealing with everything as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I will post this as an answer because it solves the problem but with a different way. I ended up writing raw SQL in scalikejdbc without escaping the tuple "names"

You can do that by using SQLSyntax class

```
val a = SQLSyntax.createUnsafely(names)
sql"${a}" <- not escaped
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have two suggetions -

1. Have you tried other types? Or do you have to use a tuple?  Maybe quickly try a Sequence or a Set, etc.
2. Also it looks like you are using raw interpolation.  I'm not sure of the API you are using but it looks like you might want to use just one quotation mark like -

   `sql"Select * from ${table} where (first_name, last_name) IN ${names}".stripMargin.map(...)`

Edit:
Could you try to map over the list or is that too hacky?  Something like
`names.map((fname, lname) => sql""" Select * from ${table} where first_name = $fname and last_name = lname""".stripMargin).for(r <- rs) yield r`

Comment: First suggestion won't help, it is a list of tuples. Making it list of lists doesn't help either